# Parsing XML in Perl using SAX

Tags: xml, perl, validation, email, sax

I need to parse an XML file into Perl using SAX - for performing the following email validation checks.

- If the 'Id' contains only alphanumeric characters and its length is between 5 and 10
- If the 'LastLoginDate' is not older than 'CreationDate'
- If 'SubscriptionMontlyFee' = 0 && 'SubscriptionType'!= free
- If 'PaymentMode' is undefined && 'SubscriptionType'!= free
- If Provision < 0
- Internal Mail exists or not
- External Mail exists or not
- If InternalMail = External Mail

Otherwise, return an alert (print a message to notify).

accounts.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Accounts locale="en_US">
  <Account>
    <Id>abcd</Id>
    <OwnerLastName>asd</OwnerLastName>
    <OwnerFirstName>zxc</OwnerFirstName>
    <Locked>false</Locked>
    <Database>mail</Database>
    <Customer>mail</Customer>
    <CreationDate year="2011" month="8" month-name="fevrier" day-of-month="19" hour-of-day="15" minute="23" day-name="dimanche"/>
    <LastLoginDate year="2015" month="04" month-name="avril" day-of-month="22" hour-of-day="11" minute="13" day-name="macredi"/>
    <LoginsCount>10405</LoginsCount>
    <Locale>nl</Locale>
    <Country>NL</Country>
    <SubscriptionType>free</SubscriptionType>
    <ActiveSubscriptionType>free</ActiveSubscriptionType>
    <SubscriptionExpiration year="1980" month="1" month-name="janvier" day-of-month="1" hour-of-day="0" minute="0" day-name="jeudi"/>
    <SubscriptionMonthlyFee>0</SubscriptionMonthlyFee>
    <PaymentMode>Undefined</PaymentMode>
    <Provision>0</Provision>
    <InternalMail>asdf@asdf.com</InternalMail>
    <ExternalMail>fdsa@zxczxc.com</ExternalMail>
    <GroupMemberships>
      <Group>werkgroep X.Y.Z.</Group>
    </GroupMemberships>
    <SynchroCount>6</SynchroCount>
    <LastSynchroDate year="2003" month="12" month-name="decembre" day-of-month="5" hour-of-day="12" minute="48" day-name="mardi"/>
    <HasActiveSync>false</HasActiveSync>
    <Company/>
  </Account>
  <Account>
    <Id>mnbv</Id>
    <OwnerLastName>cvbb</OwnerLastName>
    <OwnerFirstName>bvcc</OwnerFirstName>
    <Locked>true</Locked>
    <Database>mail</Database>
    <Customer>mail</Customer>
    <CreationDate year="2012" month="10" month-name="octobre" day-of-month="10" hour-of-day="10" minute="18" day-name="jeudi"/>
    <LastLoginDate/>
    <LoginsCount>0</LoginsCount>
    <Locale>fr</Locale>
    <Country>BE</Country>
    <SubscriptionType>free</SubscriptionType>
    <ActiveSubscriptionType>free</ActiveSubscriptionType>
    <SubscriptionExpiration year="1970" month="1" month-name="janvier" day-of-month="1" hour-of-day="1" minute="0" day-name="jeudi"/>
    <SubscriptionMonthlyFee>0</SubscriptionMonthlyFee>
    <PaymentMode>Undefined</PaymentMode>
    <Provision>0</Provision>
    <InternalMail/>
    <ExternalMail>qweqwe@qwe.com</ExternalMail>
    <GroupMemberships/>
    <SynchroCount>0</SynchroCount>
    <LastSynchroDate year="1970" month="1" month-name="janvier" day-of-month="1" hour-of-day="1" minute="0" day-name="jeudi"/>
    <HasActiveSync>false</HasActiveSync>
    <Company/>
  </Account>
</Accounts>
```

I have tried several unsuccessful attempts (follows) - and will highly appreciate your help in this regard.

Attempt for doing the parsing (but unable to retrieve values from the inner-hash).

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use XML::SAX;
my $parser = XML::SAX::ParserFactory->parser(Handler => MySAXHandler->new);
$parser->parse_uri("accounts.xml");

package MySAXHandler;
use base qw(XML::SAX::Base);

  sub start_element {
    my ($self, $el) = @_;

    my $ElementName = $el->{Name};
    my $attr = %{$el->{Attributes}};
    my $attr_value = %{$el->{Attributes}->{'LocalName'}};

    print my $loginID, "\n";      
    print $ElementName, "\n";
    print $attr_value, "\n";
  }
```

For performing the validation checks.

```
    print "Currently looking into ".(scalar @account)."elements";

    #Checking If Login only includes Alphanumeric characters and has acceptable length
    print "ALERT - ID contains invalid characters" unless ($login =~ m/[a-zA-Z@.]+$/);
    # Or print "ALERT - ID contains invalid characters" unless ($accountRef->{"Login"} =~ /^[a-zA-Z]$/);
    print "ALERT - ID length is greater than 8 characters" unless (length.$account[0] > 20);

    #print "Suspicious ALERT - Account Creation and Login time is same" unless ($account[4] != $account[5]);
    print "Suspicious ALERT - Last Login was before the account creation" unless ($account[5] > $account[4]);
    print "Suspicious ALERT - Incorrect Login Counts" unless ($account[6] > 0 && $account[5] > $account[4]);

    #Checking if Subscription Type & Active Subscription Type is same - DISCARDED
    #print "ALERT - Preferred Subscription & Current Subscription Type is not same" unless ($account[9] eq $account[10]);

    #Checking if Subscription Fee matches the Subscription Type
    if( $account[9] eq "free" && account[12] = 0) {
        #print "The user subscription is on free subscription and there are no charges" 
        return 0;
    } elsif((account[9] eq "light" || account[9] eq "regular" || account[9] eq "advanced") && account[12] <= 0) {
        print "ALERT - The user subscription is" account[9] "and he/she is not getting charged";
    } else {
        #print "The user subscription is " $account[9] "and he/she is getting charged" account[12];
        return 0;
    }

    #Checking if the Payment Mode is undefined and the subscription type is not free
    if($account[9] ne "free" && account[13] eq 'undefined') {print "ALERT - Payment mode is not being defined and the subscription type is not free"};

    #Checking if Provision is less than 0
    print "ALERT - The user balance is in negative" unless ($account[14] >= 0 );

    #Checking if Internal Email Exists or not
    print "ALERT - The user doesn't have an internal email address" unless ($account[15] != "" );

    #Checking if External Email Exists or not
    print "ALERT - The user doesn't have an external email address" unless ($account[16] != "" );

    #Checking if External Email Exists or not
    print "ALERT - The user doesn't have an external and internal email addresses are same" unless ($account[15] ne $account[16]);

    }
```

Comment: _I have tried several unsuccessful attempts_ Could you please, post (at least) one of them?

Comment: Also, if you're already familiar with [XML::LibXML](http://p3rl.org/XML::LibXML), using [XML::LibXML::Reader](http://p3rl.org/XML::LibXML::Reader) might be easier than turning to SAX.

Comment: Does it have to be `SAX`, because for stream-based parsing I like `XML::Twig` and `twig_handlers` instead.

Comment: Thanks for your response - @il_raffa included (in the question).

Comment: @choroba - it has to be SAX (set-condition by the sysadmin).

Comment: @Sobrique Unfortunately Yes (condition forwarded by the sysadmin). However, if you can provide a working example under Twig - it will also be helpful.

Comment: Also, you haven't published your clients' emails here, right?

Comment: @choroba - well yes - (those are non-existent accounts) - thanks for headlining that anyway.

Answer (score 3):

[XML::LibXML::Reader](http://p3rl.org/XML::LibXML::Reader) provides a SAX-like interface, but you can inflate the element into a full [XML::LibXML](http://p3rl.org/XML::LibXML) object when needed. The first two conditions would be tested as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

use XML::LibXML::Reader;

my $r = 'XML::LibXML::Reader'->new(location => 'file.xml') or die;
while ($r->nextElement('Account')) {
    my $xml = $r->copyCurrentNode(1);

    my $id = $xml->findvalue('Id');
    if ($id !~ /^[[:alnum:]]+$/ || 5 > length $id || 10 < length $id) {
        print "Invalid Id: $id.\n";
        next
    }

    my @dates = map $xml->findnodes($_), qw( CreationDate LastLoginDate );
    my @date_strings = map sprintf('%4d%02d%02d%02d%02d',
                                   @$_{qw{ year month day-of-month hour-of-day minute }}),
                           @dates;
    if ($date_strings[0] gt $date_strings[1]) {
        print "Invalid dates for $id: @date_strings.\n";
    }

    ...
}
```

Note that `LastLoginDate` for "robynsa" is empty, so it can't be compared to `CreationDate`.

Comment: Thanks choroba for providing a neat LibXML approach for doing the stuff which I had asked for - but unfortunately, the XML files which we have are extremely big (20 to 30 gigs each) and we may have to run the validation script simultaneously on all of them - which somehow has forced us to use a Stream-based Parser (for eg. SAX) in order to avoid halting our servers where all those files resides.

Comment: @MSalman: That's the point. [XML::LibXML::Reader](http://p3rl.org/XML::LibXML::Reader) is stream based.

Comment: That's what I also told to my SysTeam - but they don't consider it as a reliable option and had set a condition to only go with SAX.

Answer (score 0):

Well, with `XML::Twig` I'd approach it something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Twig; 
use Time::Piece; 

sub process_account {
    my ( $twig, $account ) = @_;
    print $account -> first_child_text('Id'),"\n";
    if ( $account -> first_child_text('Id') =~ m/^\w{5,10}$/ ) { 
        print "Id OK\n";
    }

    my $logindate = join ( "-", map { $account -> first_child('LastLoginDate')->att($_) // 0 } qw ( year month day-of-month ) );

    my $createdate = join ( "-", map { $account -> first_child('CreationDate')->att($_) // 0 } qw ( year month day-of-month ) );
    if ( eval{ Time::Piece -> strptime ( $logindate, "%Y-%m-%d" )} > eval{Time::Piece -> strptime ( $createdate, "%Y-%m-%d" )} ) {
         print "Create Date OK\n"; 
    }

    if (    $account -> first_child_text('SubscriptionMonthlyFee') eq '0'
        and $account -> first_child_text('SubscriptionType') eq 'free' ) {
       print "Subscription Type fee OK\n"; 

    }
    $twig -> purge; #empty data processed so far. 
}

my $twig = XML::Twig -> new ( twig_handlers => { 'Account' => \&process_account } );
   $twig -> parsefile ( 'your_xml_file');
```

We set a handler on `Account` elements, which gets passed each as we go. We extract fields from the record, and validate them (this just prints, you should perhaps invert the logic and abort/warn etc.).

We also use `purge` because one of the major reasons to use a `SAX` style parser is memory footprint.

Comment: Thanks for providing a working example - and it did help but unfortunately the XML file which we have is extremely large (20 to 30 gigs) and therefore we are forced to use a Stream-Based Parser (for e.g SAX) in order to avoid halting our servers where all those files resides. However, I did take up that script and enhanced it further to leverage my understanding of twig.

Comment: This is a stream based parser. `XML:Twig`. That's what that `purge` is doing - emptying the XML we have already parsed from memory. (It does keep 'unfinished' tags still)

Comment: XML::Twig which is a more 'Perl-like' API - does not exactly do things as Stream-based parser does (we don't want a full tree instead just a portion of it to work on) but twigs do keep the path of their predecessor nodes and the memory efficiency is also not upto the mark (which is the core requirement of the situation). However, pudge is beneficial but as you already said that (It does keep 'unfinished' tags).
Thanks for your concern (and I may need your guidance, since I'm working on this twig thing as a side-task).

Comment: You may find `twig_roots` relevant to your needs too then. "The twig_roots mode builds only the required sub-trees from the document Anything outside of the twig roots will just be ignored:"

Comment: I have changed the question which has been marked "duplicate" by yourself and would like to request you to give it a look now.
For twig_roots (will definitely check it out) - thanks.

Comment: Question has been reopened as a result. Given a go at offering an answer too.